# Float images under one another

Tags: html, image, css-float

Is it possible to have images float to the right under one another, preferably without any CSS or div tags because I'm not too experienced with them, but any solution is welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This would be easiest with a `<div>` - no need to be scared, it's just a box!

```
<div style="float:right">
    <img src="image1.png" /><br />
    <img src="image2.png" /><br />
    <img src="image3.png" /><br />
    <img src="image4.png" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`img{float:right; clear:right; }`

Answer (score 0):

With the use of HTML tags...definitely not your best choice, but

```
<br>
```

causes a line-break and will automatically break your next element to the next line.

```
<p>One
<br>
<p>This will break to the next line.
<br>
<br>
<p>Two line-breaks before this one.
```

If you want, you can use simple CSS right on your HTML page by adding

```
<style>
.p {display:[inline][block][inline-block]};
</style>
```

[Further information on CSS display property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)